# How to check if today is monday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

To know the year, I use `<%= Time.now.year %>`.

So I can check the year using `<% if Time.now.year == 2020 %>You are living the 2020!<% end %>`.

But... how to check if today is Monday? Or Sunday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> Time.now.monday?
=> false
> 2.days.ago.monday?
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use .monday? on Date.today

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-monday-3F

And you can use .year if you need to compare to 2020 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```rb
Time.now.wday
# => 3

# this means it's wednesday
```

`wday` stands for Week day. And `0` stands for sunday and `6` stands for saturday.

So for monday you can check: `Time.now.wday == 1`, for sunday you can check: `Time.now.wday == 0`